# Why does some US banknotes have abstract art on the reverse instead of detailed scenes of history/monuments?

Tags: united-states, numismatics

Most US paper currency has detailed images of national monuments or historical scenes on the reverse side. Why wasn't the same treatment given to all currency, such as the $500 bill? It simply features lots of 500s.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the only ones like this are the large denomination bank notes, $500, $1000, $10,000, and that one $100,000 note. These were always rare for obvious reasons and none has been issued since the 1960s. So I don't know if this is the reason but I don't imagine there was much need to make them pretty.

Comment: You can go to the [US Bureau of Printing and Engraving's website](https://www.moneyfactory.gov/100000goldcertificate.html) and see pictures of the various large denomination bills. Earlier 1918 versions do have "reverse vignettes" such as Washington resigning his commission or the Pilgrims.